# Sending specific sheet in Workbook to Specified email stored in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code for sending emails stored in sheet5 with an attachment, any one sheet of the workbook . When name of sheet matches with value in column A, it should select email from Column B and attach the sheet with same Name.

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Dim i As Integer

    While (Sheet5.Cells(1, i) <> vbNullString)

    If (sh.Name = Sheet5.Range("a" & i).Value) Then
        sh.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

        TempFileName = "Sheet " & sh.Name & " of " _
                     & ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With wb
            .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = Sheet5.Range("b" & i).Value
                .CC = Sheet5.Range("c" & i).Value
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
                .Body = "Hi there"
                .Attachments.Add wb.FullName
                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing

        Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
End If

Wend

Next sh
```

> ' i am getting error at while loop "While (Sheet5.Cells(1, i) <>
>   vbNullString)" and at If statement "If (sh.Name = Sheet5.Range("a" &
>   i).Value) Then"

Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you are showing is complete, `i` does not have a value is is defaulting to 0. Any ranges you state referencing `i` will error out since there is no row or column index equal to 0.

You need to give `i` a value larger than 0